# Android project not running in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I have installed all version of Eclipse and SDK manager many times, but when I create new project and run it shows loading 100% but noting happens but when built with existing source code project it works fine. Can any one help me fix my prob of running new projects?

Comment: Hi, eclipse and the Android sdk can be a little tricky to set up. How did you install the sdk? How did you link it to eclipse? Have you done a reinstall? Can you show a logcat/stacktrace/log anything really that eclipse is throwing out. Have you tried this: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html Can you outline the steps you are taking in setting up a new project?

Comment: When you run your own project, what does the console read?

Comment: @Benito: console is empty! it gives me no info

Comment: @RossC : i followed the steps from website which yu have mention only! sdk i have installed using the installer provided for windows .i am just tring to run hello world program which i created.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the eclipse workspace folder properties and make sure that it has got full access permissions. Then clean the project and run again. also while cleaning, please make sure that the files inside project's bin folder are getting deleted or not.

Comment: the files are not deleted inside the bin folder it waits at 98%

Answer (score 0):

Do all the instructions on the Lars Vogel page - [Android Training](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html#installation).